# Problem installing Rubi on Mac OS X ARM

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, rubi

I installed the Rubi package by using
`ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["RuleBasedIntegration","Rubi"]` 
but when I use it, it only gives me the original function without calculate like this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Details for the versions

```
13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)
```

and

```
Rubi 4.16.1.0
```

Comment: Are you sure that it has been properly installed? For instance, if you do `$RubiVersion` or `First[PacletFind["Rubi"]]["Location"]` do you get any answers?

Comment: Yes, the outputs are "Rubi 4.16.1.0" and the correct path.

Comment: Can you try in a clean kernel? `Quit[]`, then ``<<Rubi` `` and then the command for the integral? I tried to do the integral in `Rubi` and works fine for me

Comment: I tried however it didn’t work 

Comment: Please include the output of `$Version` and your OS info to the post.

Comment: Thanks, it's `13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)`

Comment: I have the same output as you've shown with Rubi working OK. Have you tried restarting your Mac?

Comment: Yes, but it didn’t work.

Comment: @dcmpsr does this happen with other integrals as well or just this one?

Comment: Every integral has this problem.

Comment: may be problem with ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]? I never install Rubi this way. Try https://rulebasedintegration.org/downloadRubi.html  and use the command `PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]`,  Once installed, it goes to (on windows) ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35pIK.png)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!